# Authentication error and java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

Tags: tomcat

In a java web application running in tomcat I get the following errors in the server log:

```
    2018-03-16 13:18:49,456 ERROR [Caesium-1-3]  c.a.scheduler.core.JobLauncher Scheduled job with ID 'IndexingAnalyticsJob' failed
    rx.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at rx.observables.BlockingObservable$8.call(BlockingObservable.java:642)
        at rx.observables.BlockingObservable$8.call(BlockingObservable.java:639)
        at rx.observables.BlockingObservable$9.onError(BlockingObservable.java:673)
        at rx.internal.operators.NotificationLite.accept(NotificationLite.java:147)
        at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.subscribe(BlockingObservable.java:528)
        at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.subscribe(BlockingObservable.java:665)
        at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.subscribe(BlockingObservable.java:639)
        at 
...
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:357)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1895)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeToObservableFuture$ToObservableFuture.call(OnSubscribeToObservableFuture.java:74)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeToObservableFuture$ToObservableFuture.call(OnSubscribeToObservableFuture.java:43)
        at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:8264)
        at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:8231)
        at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.subscribe(BlockingObservable.java:507)
        ... 16 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultConnectingIOReactor.processEvent(DefaultConnectingIOReactor.java:173)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultConnectingIOReactor.processEvents(DefaultConnectingIOReactor.java:147)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.execute(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:350)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.execute(PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.java:191)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase$1.run(CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase.java:64)
        ... 1 common frames omitted
```

But it only happens from time to time so I am suspecting network outages, are there any good tools to investigate this/traffic etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to latest version of the project dependencies seems to have solved the issue.